# Android InApp Purchase Different Location

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test displaying the price for in In App purchase using Google Play in my android app.

The code I have written works and displays the price in my currency. Now I want to test if the price is displayed correctly if purchased from another location.

For example I am in the UK and I see the GBP price, I want to change my location so I see the USD price.

I have tried spoofing my GPS but that doesn't work.

Is it possible to spoof my location so I can see the price in a different currency?

Comment: What about Setting Country in Device. Or in Your Google Account?

Comment: In Google play you can only change your country location once a year